# How to create and apply a list of values in R code?

Tags: r, list, fill

I defined a list of 3 colors. And I created another combined value which reflects that colors list. When I ran the code with 3 single hex colors or one defined color, it was okay. But when I applied the list of 3 defined colors, or applied the combined value in the code, it went wrong.

I defined a list of 3 colors.

```
gcf_yellow <- "#f5f43f"
gcf_sushi <- "#80c344"
ieu_maroon <- "#a13458"
```

And I created another combined value which reflects that colors list.
`cvi_colors = c(gcf_yellow, gcf_sushi, ieu_maroon`

1. When I ran the code with 3 single hex colors, it was okay.

```
ggplot(dat_stages, aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = c("#a13458", "#80c344", "#f5f43f"))
```

2. It was also okay if I applied single defined color, as this

```
ggplot(dat_stages, aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = ieu_maroon)
```

3. But if I replaced them with the defined values, it went wrong.

```
ggplot(dat_stages, aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = c(ieu_maroon, gcf_sushi, gcf_yellow))
```

4. It also went wrong if I applied the combined value, as this

```
ggplot(dat_stages, aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = cvi_colors)
```

Could someone explain why (3) and (4) go wrong and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does "it went wrong" mean?

Comment: In ggplot, you should only pass a single color in `fill = ....`, to give all the bars a single color. If you want multiple fills to represent a variable in your data, you have to _map_ the fill to that variable. This is what `aes` does. For example, try `aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg, fill = factor(Sub_Year))`. Once the fill aesthetic is mapped to a variable, you can specify the actual colours by adding `+ scale_fill_manual(values = cvi_colors)` to your plot.

Comment: Thanks Roland. It says error with fill. And thanks Allan for explaining it to me. It works. And I have a minor question: in this case, the legend title of Sub_Year appears as "factor(Sub_Year). Is there any way to rephrase it nicely?

Comment: There are two ways to get around your legend title issue: 

1. If you mutate the `Sub_Year` variable to a factor first then the legend will not have the factor prefix e.g `dat_stages %>% mutate Sub_year = factor(Sub_Year) %>% ggplot(aes(...))`

2. use the `name` argument in `scale_fill_manual` e.g.`+ scale_fill_manual(name = "Sub Year", values = cvi_colors)`